# Edge Collider on Tilemap via Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am currently working on a game in Unity and I have a huge problem. I want to draw a level with a tilemap and then move the player on this tilemap. But I want to add an edge collider with the script at the start of the level, because I want to include a Level-Creator in the game. So, I cannot create every collider manual.

Here is an example picture of a "level":
[image]

I want to have an edge collider to prevent moving outside the tilemap, but I do not know how to implement that in code. I either cannot find anything helpful on web.

I would be glad about any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

If you get the Collider component of your tilemap, you are able to access the "OverlapPoint" method. With this method you're able to make a basic edge detection system for your custom tile map.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OverlapPoint.html

What I would do is:
Save Your player's current position in a "lastPosition" variable, check for every update if the corners are inside the collider with the "OverlapPoint" method. If not: do not save the current position but set the current position of the player to the lastPosition variable.

```
public Vector3 playerSize;
public Collider2d collider;
Vector2 lastPosition;

void Start()
{
    lastPosition = transform.position;
}

void Update()
{
    if(!collider.OverlapPoint(transform.position) ||
        !collider.OverlapPoint(transform.position + playerSize) ||
        !collider.OverlapPoint(transform.position + new Vector2(playerSize.x, 0)) ||
        !collider.OverlapPoint(transform.position + new Vector2(0, playerSize.y)))
    {
        transform.position = lastPosition;
    }

    lastPosition = transform.position;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it, but I am not sure if this meets my requirements. But yeah, thanks xd